# Extract a part from a string by searching with 2 keywords

Tags: php, search, extract

```
$string="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
```

Lets say I want to find `'typesetting industry.'` and  `'1960s'` from the `$string` and if available those words/sentence extract the rest text between those words and save into a variable.

So extracted text will be

```
$extracted_text="Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the ";
```

> Note that word count doesn't work in my case
>
> Assumed 'typesetting industry.' and  '1960s' are unique and must have
>   in my string.

How do I find and extract like this?

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a simple `(.*)` (capture everything) regex surrounded by your search strings `/$start(.*)$end/`. Since the search strings may contain regex special characters you should also escape them using `preg_quote`.

```
$start = preg_quote("typesetting industry.");
$end = preg_quote("1960s");

$pattern = "/$start(.*)$end/";
$string = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";

preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Alternatively you can also split the string using the keywords

```
$start = "typesetting industry.";
$end = "1960s";

$string = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
$exploded = explode($end, explode($start, $string)[1]);

echo $exploded[0];
```